# how to find the outermost boundary among a group of boundaries

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology

I'd like to know what algorithm I could use to tell the outermost boundary in an open mesh with disk-like topology.
Basically, exactly like the isHole mathlab function; here's the relevant [mathlab example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyshape.ishole.html#d117e1106011).
Thank you.

Comment: You have to provide many more details to make your question answerable. For instance: (1) What do you mean by "disk-like topology"? Do you mean a triangulated 2-dimensional disk? (2) What do you mean by holes? (3) The boundary of what? I suspect, you want an algorithm which tells you if a vertex of a triangulated disk likes on the boundary of the disk.  For this, indeed, there is a simple algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, thought the mathlab example was clear. It's yes to all your questions, except the last one; an algorithm for finding a boundary vertex can be found, for instance, in libigl: https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/master/include/igl/is_border_vertex.h. My real problem is instead how to tell different boundaries, and which one can be considered the "outermost boundary"... a relevant discussion is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968478/how-to-detect-a-hole-in-the-triangular-mesh

Comment: (cont'ed) In short, it seems to me the mathlab example isHole function is telling which is which based on boundary length or geometric outside / inside check... probably the first. I edited the question, hopefully more clearer